# Moment.js Day Ago

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a problem. 
I create chat, I use to this moment js. Variable (this.entry.createdData) has date hours of sent message. I would like to display if caller sent me a message yesterday / day before yesterday or in the format DAY: MONTH. Unfortunately it does not work. When message was posted yesterday at 16.15 and today is 15.15 it shows today's date instead of yesterday. Ideas?

```
    var mom = moment(this.entry.createdDate),
            now = moment(),
            diffInDays = mom.from(now),
            diffInYears = now.diff(mom, 'years');

    if( diffInYears!== 0 ){
        return mom.format('DD MM YYYY')
    }
    else{
        if( diffInDays === "1 day ago" )
            return 'Yesterday';
        else if( diffInDays === "2 days ago" )
            return 'Day Before Yesterday';
        else 
            return mom.format('DD MM');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Actually, I cannot :( Sorry, but i can show you output from console.log, Would you like to? Or I can update / asnwer your questions, if you want to.

Comment: What is the value of `this.entry.createdData`? What type is it?

Comment: @zgrybus ok, what is an example value of `this.entry.createdData`? Just trying to reproduce your scenario.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to decide "yesterday" by comparing the time with start of today. If the time is between start of yesterday and start of today, then it is.

Checkout APIs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/